# Ruby on Rails connect to server issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am working with Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Third Edition) by Michael Hartl.  I am currently in chapter 1 and have been able to download Ruby on Rails-v 4.2.0. I have made all the adjustment within the Gemfile and was successful in connecting to my sever. However, once I closed the server I have not been able to reconnect and get an error message

> You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version
>   requirements. You Specified:sqlite3 (>_0) and sqlite3 (=1.3.9)

I tried to search on Google but did not find the answer. Any help or suggestions would be wonderful!

Comment: More details needed. Please EDIT your question and post your gemfile contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is saying it all:

```
You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. You Specified:sqlite3 (>_0) and sqlite3 (=1.3.9)
```

You must have mistakenly specified the `sqlite3` gem twice in your `Gemfile`. Remove one of them (possibly the older one), then run:

```
bundle install
```

and re-start your rails server.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: it was the sqlite3 gem that was entered twice! Thanks so much